# Can we call JavaScript collection.reduce() method with parameter object collection instead of primitive data?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and was reading about High order functions like map, filter, and reduce.
For hands on I tried following example:
Assume there are some items in shopping cart, use reduce to calculate total cost of items.

```
var products = [{
    "id": 100,
    "name": "Dell laptop",
    "category": "Laptop",
    "price": 40000
}, {
    "id": 100,
    "name": "LG Mobile",
    "category": "Mobile",
    "price": 20000
}, {
    "id": 100,
    "name": "HP laptop",
    "category": "Laptop",
    "price": 60000
}, {
    "id": 100,
    "name": "Samsung Mobile",
    "category": "Mobile",
    "price": 25000
}];
var total = 0;
var result = products.reduce(function (total, product) {
    return total + parseInt(product.price);
});

console.log("Total cost of cart : " + result);
```

Output of the above code was something like below:

```
Total cost of cart : [object Object]200006000025000
```

Now I modified the above code and added map as well them it works fine:

```
var result = products.map(function (product) {
    return product.price;
}).reduce(function (total, price) {
    return total + price;
});
```

I get correct result.

Now my question is why I am not able to use the reduce API alone?

Comment: For `reduce()` to work, you need to pass in the initial value of `total` as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. There is no need of two `reduce` calls. Just pass the initial value as `0` as last parameter to the `reduce`.

```
var total = products.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr.price;
}, 0);
// ^^ Initial value
```

```js
var products = [{
    "id": 100,
    "name": "Dell laptop",
    "category": "Laptop",
    "price": 40000
}, {
    "id": 100,
    "name": "LG Mobile",
    "category": "Mobile",
    "price": 20000
}, {
    "id": 100,
    "name": "HP laptop",
    "category": "Laptop",
    "price": 60000
}, {
    "id": 100,
    "name": "Samsung Mobile",
    "category": "Mobile",
    "price": 25000
}];


var total = products.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr.price;
}, 0);

document.body.innerHTML = total;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

> `arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])`
>
> ...
>
> The first time the callback is called, `previousValue` and `currentValue` can be one of two values. If `initialValue` is provided in the call to `reduce`, then `previousValue` will be equal to `initialValue` and `currentValue` will be equal to the first value in the array. **If no `initialValue` was provided, then `previousValue` will be equal to the first value in the array and `currentValue` will be equal to the second.**

Since you are not providing an initial value, your very first operation is actually `{id: ...} + 20000`. You need to provide an `initialValue` of `0` to fix that behaviour.